# What is with the Google timer durations?

Tags: google-search

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Etc.....

I'm unable to see the pattern here.

What's more weird, is that it works if you specify any interval (including some or all) of "second", "min" or "hour" less than 24 hours.

[image]

Fractions and other expressions don't seem to do anything either. "timer 1000" works but "timer 999" does't.

And then there's this:

[image]

**What is Google doing here?**

Comment: whats your question exactly?

Comment: How do we get from "timer _x_" to the numbers seen?

Comment: for me its always 5 - https://i.stack.imgur.com/eozVj.png - for all inputs: timer0, timer 1, timer 2, timer 3, timer 4, etc.

Comment: Weird. I just tried "timer 2" in an incognito tab and got different numbers each time. I also tried "timer 100" and got 1h 52m 04s. I would expect it would default to a certain integer number of hours/minutes/seconds (probably minutes considering how most people use these timers.

Comment: I also just tried "timer 1000" and got a timer but "timer 999" didn't work.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WR2fn.png - https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxQij.png

Comment: Right. So wtf is going on here? I'm getting the same numbers in incognito tabs and otherwise on different computers. And then different numbers on different browsers and different IPs. And none of them make any more sense than "every timer is five minutes".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The timer is interpreting numbers ≤ 2400 as times.**

Any number < 1300 is assumed to be as 4-digit 12-hour time but you can zero-pad the hour to use 23-hour time.
Any number ≤ 12 is assumed to be just the hours.

For example, these screenshots were taken as if I were in a UTC time zone around 11:20 UTC:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I assume the OS/browser combo used by [user0](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/186471/user0) is not giving google location information (either via location, IP or being signed into a Google Maps account), so it defaults to five minutes.